# Change safari password manager color in css

Tags: css, web, safari

This might be a completely silly question but I haven't found the answer yet.
I would like to know how to change the color of safari password manager.
I would like it to be the same color as the text.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you can't change the color of the browser UI. I would suggest changing the field color to something lighter

Comment: Ouch... The problem is that in Light mode it's perfect. But in Dark mode it does not change color.

Comment: @Alexys I was thinking maybe it would be possible to programmatically trick the browser into turning on dark mode (so it would change the keychain icon to a lighter color), but Safari doesn't change the color of the keychain icon to something lighter even if the browser is in dark mode :/